# What is the best way to customize the design/skin of mediawiki?

Tags: css, mediawiki

I'm new to mediawiki and want to make my own skin for a mediawiki. For example I have a button (div.button-field > input) and I want to give it height: 100%. I know you can put it in a custom.css like

```
div.button-field > input {height: 100%;}
```

But if I do it for every element I want to customize the .css gets very long. The other thing, if I want only to customize a specific button which is nested like "div > div.container > form > div > div.button-field > input" and I add a div or remove a div, then it wont work anymore and I have to adjust the "path". So what would be the right way todo it? Or is the .css the best way todo it?

With kind regards
Oli

Answer (score 0):

The answers depend on how much you want to change.

1. The first easiest path is to find an existing skin, see on [MediaWiki.org](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:All_skins).
2. You can configure some elements like [the logo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLogo), [the favicon](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgFavicon) or [the sidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/Sidebar), and you can change every [text message of the interface](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:System_message).
3. Then, you can customise, as a logged-in administrator, the CSS rules by modifying the page **MediaWiki:Common.css** (example on [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css)), or possibly **MediaWiki:YourSkinName.css** for skin-specific rules (for example MediaWiki:Vector.css to modify only the skin Vector; example on [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Vector.css)).

   You can also modify add JavaScript features by modifying **MediaWiki:Common.js** (example on [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.js)), or **MediaWiki:YourSkinName.js** for skin-specific rules (for example MediaWiki:Vector.js to modify only the skin Vector; the page does not exist on the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Vector.js)).

   This kind of modification is recommended because it will be kept during MediaWiki updates, although minor adaptations could be needed on the long term.
4. If you want heavier changes, you can copy an existing skin, rename it, and change the PHP code, for instance by moving or deleting entire blocks. Prefer copying a well-supported skin like Vector or Monobook to be sure it is compatible with most MediaWiki extensions.

   But it will take some or lot of work during MediaWiki updates (depends on the quantity of changes), and if you cannot do this work the risk is either you custom skin breaks or you will stay with an old MediaWiki version (which is not recommended for security reasons).

   Also, if you choose this path, be warn not to break the structure expected by the VisualEditor if you want it continues to work.

There is a tutorial on MediaWiki.org to adapt the skinning from easiest ways to heaviest, see [Manual:Skinning Part 1](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_1) and next pages.